# python threading and progressbars

Tags: python, multithreading, progress-bar, ttk, nonetype

Hello I am relitively new to python and I have a copple of questions regarding a script I was trying to write (below).
`

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk
import time
import threading
def foo():
    time.sleep(5) # simulate some work
def start_foo_thread():
    global foo_thread
    foo_thread = threading.Thread(target=foo)
    foo_thread.daemon = True
    print("it ran")
    stepprogress.start()
    foo_thread.start()
    root.after(20, check_foo_thread)

def check_foo_thread():
    if foo_thread.is_alive():
        root.after(20, check_foo_thread)
    else:
        stepprogress.stop()
def cancel():
    print("cancelling")
def backround():
    print("running in background")
root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.grid()
tk.Label( frame, text="importing").grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2)
tk.Label( frame, text="starting").grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2)
stepprogress = ttk.Progressbar(frame, orient="horizontal", length=200, mode="determinate").grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=2)
tk.Label( frame, text="overall progress").grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=2)
mainprogress = ttk.Progressbar(frame, orient="horizontal", length=200, mode="determinate").grid(row=5, column=1, columnspan=2)
tk.Button(frame, text="Cancel", command=cancel).grid(row=6, column=1)
tk.Button(frame, text="run in background", command=backround).grid(row=6, column=2)
frame.pack()
start_foo_thread()
root.mainloop()
```

`

Below are my questions.

```
1.no matter what I do I always get "nonetype has no attribute start?
2.also I was wondering about how I could safely close the thread and the window when someone hits cancel?
3.I also wondered how I could make it that when someone hits the "background" button the window could close, but not the thread?
4.Is it possible for me to have the process to be threaded in a different file, how so?
```

I am more of an `html/javascript` coder than a python programmer.

Thanks in advance,
John S

Answer (score 3):

1) it's because you're assigning the return of the *grid* method, **None**, to *stepprogress*; you  can fix it this way:

```
stepprogress = ttk.Progressbar(frame, orient="horizontal", length=200, mode="determinate")
stepprogress.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=2)
```

2) you could use a **flag** to control the execution of the thread, then wait for it to end properly before exiting:

```
def foo():
    global load
    i = 1
    while load and i <= 10:
        print("running...")
        time.sleep(1) # simulate some work
        i = i + 1
    print("end of thread")
...
def cancel():
    global load
    load = False
    while foo_thread.is_alive():
        print("waiting thread...")
        time.sleep(0.1)
    print("exiting...")
    root.destroy()
```

3) you can use *root.withdraw()* to hide the window:

```
def backround():
    print("running in background")
    root.withdraw()
```

Here is a sample to sum it up:

```
import tkinter as tk
import ttk
import time
import threading
def foo():
    i = 1
    while load and i <= 10:
        print("running...")
        time.sleep(1) # simulate some work
        i = i + 1
    print("end of thread")
def start_foo_thread():
    global foo_thread
    foo_thread = threading.Thread(target=foo)
    foo_thread.daemon = True
    print("it ran")
    stepprogress.start()
    foo_thread.start()
    root.after(20, check_foo_thread)

def check_foo_thread():
    if foo_thread.is_alive():
        root.after(20, check_foo_thread)
    else:
        stepprogress.stop()
def cancel():
    global load
    load = False
    while foo_thread.is_alive():
        print("waiting thread...")
        time.sleep(0.1)
    print("exiting...")
    root.destroy()
def backround():
    print("running in background")
    root.withdraw()
root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.grid()
load = True
tk.Label( frame, text="importing").grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2)
tk.Label( frame, text="starting").grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2)
stepprogress = ttk.Progressbar(frame, orient="horizontal", length=200, mode="determinate")
stepprogress.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=2)
tk.Label( frame, text="overall progress").grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=2)
mainprogress = ttk.Progressbar(frame, orient="horizontal", length=200, mode="determinate").grid(row=5, column=1, columnspan=2)
tk.Button(frame, text="Cancel", command=cancel).grid(row=6, column=1)
tk.Button(frame, text="run in background", command=backround).grid(row=6, column=2)
frame.pack()
start_foo_thread()
root.mainloop()
```

4) What do you mean by "to have the process to be threaded in a different file", isolating the thread function in another **module**?...